# Full backup feature is disabled by gservice

Tags: android, adb, android-backup-service

I am attempting to perform a full backup on Android using `adb shell bmgr fullbackup` but I am seeing:

```
I/Backup: [GmsBackupTransport] Attempt to do full backup on com.alexrothberg.afitness
I/Backup: [GmsBackupTransport] Full backup feature is disabled by gservice.
```

I don't see this issue [listed on the support page](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/testingbackup.html#Troubleshooting).

Answer (score 1):

Most likely your trying this on Android version <6.0 (that's when I saw it). As in https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/autobackup.html you need to be running Android 6.0 or greater.